# Why this question is off topic and how to make it on topic?

Tags: discussion

[Does it make sense to buy this voltage stabilizer for this air conditioner?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559880/does-it-make-sense-to-buy-this-voltage-stabilizer-for-this-air-conditioner)

I really don't think it's not about electrical engineering. I can't find any other suitable website to know scientific reasons for it.

Comment: It's there in EESE policy: Product recommendations are out of topic.

Comment: @MituRaj did I ask for product recommendation? I asked about a logic if that logic is correct or not.

Comment: That's right. Just because I told you the site policy, you never had to take it personal and go with a downvoting spree on my profile. I noticed you did 5 downvotes in last hour, and I have 5 down votes in a row in my notification in matter of minutes. I don't think it was a coincidence. I hope mods look into this and take appropriate action.

Comment: The fact that you "can't find any other suitable website" doesn't make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did **not** ask about general requirements or uses of voltage stabilizers. Your question was very clearly focused on one specific consumer product that you were considering: should I "buy **this** voltage stabilizer".

Any time a question asks about whether a **specific item** is "suitable" or "the best choice" then the question becomes a product recommendation.

Furthermore, questions about the use of consumer appliances are off topic. Your question was off-topic for both reasons.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've edited it. Is it better now?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so. You are still referring to a specific product, and the question is still about the **use** of consumer products rather than the **design** of electronics. EE.SE is just not a good site for this kind of question.